# Gerar elementos HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5, json

Preciso criar um código que após passar alguns parâmetros ele gera-se um gráfico parecido com a imagem abaixo, pensei em criar uma tabela para cada atividade.
Alguém tem alguma dica, ou conhece um artigo que possa me ajudar?
Penso em usar ***Json*** para passar os dados (sei trabalhar com ***Json***), meu problema seria criar essa *function* em ***Javascript***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa tabela é definida por dependências, como vemos na imagem a atividade **B** é dependente da atividade **A**

Meu Json terá uma estrutura parecida com essa abaixo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Venda/GetDadosItensVenda",
        success: function (itensVenda) {

            if (itensVenda != null) {

                $('#tbody').children().remove();

                $(itensVenda).each(function (i) {

                    var tbody = $('#tbody');
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr +=
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].CodigoProduto;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Quantidade;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario;
                    tr += "<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-info' onclick=Editar(" + itensVenda[i].Id + ")>" + "Editar";
                    tr += "<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=Deletar(" + itensVenda[i].Id + ")>" + "Deletar";

                    tbody.append(tr);

                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`

Comment: Quando você diz "um gráfico" você se refere à imagem inteira? E é importante que seja tudo uma imagem? No meu entender, o mais simples seria criar várias tabelas mesmo (já que é mais fácil criar e estilizar elementos no DOM do que desenhar tabelas arbitrárias num canvas), posicionando-as de forma absoluta numa área da página. As setas poderiam ser uma única imagem, rotacionada com CSS. P.S. *Ainda que* seja importante gerar uma imagem, há [uma biblioteca](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) que consegue transformar o resultado visual da página em uma imagem.

Comment: A propósito, você já sabe ou já definiu como seria esse JSON? Seria apenas uma descrição declarativa dos dados (e o programa desenha como quer) ou teria também especificado o posicionamento? Se não definiu. eu sugeriria uma lista de listas, a ser desenhada da esquerda pra direita, onde cada elemento ou é "início" ou é uma estrutura com os valores da tabela (as tabelas sempre têm o mesmo formato, certo?). Só uma dúvida: todos os elementos da direita são "alcançáveis" por todos os elementos da esquerda? Poderia por exemplo ter um E com seta saindo de B mas não de C?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não seria uma imagem não, seria várias tabelas mesmo. Eu editei a minha pergunta com um Json parecido com que quero usar.

Comment: Obrigatoriamente tem que ser nesse layout? Pergunto porque temos vários frameworks que podem ajudar a montar um gráfico. Porém nesse layout acho difícil. Até porque não parece um gráfico rsrs

Comment: Não que precisa ser um gráfico, basta ser algo visual para informar as dependências entre atividades.
Estou aberto a sugestões.

Answer (score 1):

JC, no seu exemplo você está esquecendo de fechar as tags, em todo caso eu usaria um template para montar o HTML.

Segue um exemplo com HandleBars.

```js
$(function () {

  var source = $("#tmpl-registros").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var tabela = $('#tbody');
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Venda/GetDadosItensVenda",
    success: function (itensVenda) {
      if (itensVenda != null) {
        var html = template(itensVenda);
        tabela.html(html);
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      var itensVenda = [];
      for (var indice = 1; indice <= 20; indice++) {
        itensVenda.push({
          Id: indice, 
          CodigoProduto: indice, 
          Quantidade: indice, 
          PrecoUnitario: 1.23 * indice
        });
      }

      var html = template(itensVenda);
      tabela.html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CodigoProduto</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>PrecoUnitario</th>
      <th>Editar</th>
      <th>Deletar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>

<script id="tmpl-registros" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{CodigoProduto}}</td>
    <td>{{Quantidade}}</td>
    <td>{{PrecoUnitario}}</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-info' onclick=Editar({{Id}})>Editar</button></td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=Deletar({{Id}})>Deletar</button></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente isto:

```
<script>
function sua_funcao(parametroA) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","cria_tabela.php?parametro="+parametroA,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Este código vai no head de sua página, ele pega uma página isolada "cria_tabela.php" e alimenta o item "tabela" no seu código com o resultado desta página, assim você pode continuar a programar PHP com poucas linhas de JavaScript.

Este é o item a ser alimentado:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="tabela" >
</div>
```

E na `cria_tabela` teria suas tabelas criadas em PHP.

Se ainda não conhece, recomendo dar uma pesquisada em bootstrap, para melhor aparência da página.